# Linux Kernel Development Support for RSA Encryption

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, cryptography

I am working on a prototype, and I'm new to Linux Kernel Development.  I see that the Linux Kernel has a crypto module, but I am not sure if it supports Asymmetric Encryption such as RSA.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the linux kernel does provide support for RSA Encryption since there is a rsa.c file under the crypto directory of the linux kernel source code.